# What value explicit constructor brings when arguments passed are custom type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand the value of keyword `explicit` when used in cases where there is a chance of creating ambiguity, like the examples I am seeing [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) and [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/059600298X/re41.html).

Which I understand as prevents implicit conversion of basic types to object type, and this makes sense.

```
struct point {explicit point(int x, int y = 0);
};
point p2 = 10; // Error: would be OK without explicit
```

What I want to understand is what value `explicit` brings when I am using custom datatypes as constructor argument?

```
struct X {X(int x);}; // a sample custom datatype I am referring to.

struct pointA { pointA(X x);}; // here this looks to me same as 
    
struct pointB {explicit pointB(X x);}; // like here this 
    
int main() {

    pointA pa = 10; // fails as expected
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the confusion? The benefit when "using using custom datatypes as constructor argument" is "prevents implicit conversion [...] to object type". It's the same situation as for basic types. If you want to specialize to your specific example, it's a bit trickier to have a literal `X` object than to have a literal `int`, but otherwise the principles are the same. *Maybe you should change your initialization to `pointA pa = X{10};` so that you are in fact trying to initialize a `pointA` with an `X`?*

Comment: @JaMiT I am not confused. I am just almost at a point of clarity where I can say `explicit` makes no sense when constructor is working with custom types as arguments. I am just verifying am I missing anything with that inference.

Comment: Playing word games is not productive. See definition 1 of [confusion @ Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confusion): *"A lack of clarity or order"*. If you are "almost at a point of clarity" then you lack some degree of clarity; there is some degree of confusion. I advise you to not argue semantics, but instead explain your viewpoint. I stated that there is no significant difference between the "basic types" and "custom datatypes" cases. You apparently think there is. What is that difference that you see?

Comment: @JaMiT are you at peace now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of `explicit` has nothing to do with the parameter list, it has to do with the type being constructed, especially if there are side-effects.  For example, consider `std::ofstream`.

```
void foo(std::ofstream out_file);
// ...
foo("some_file.txt");
```

Without `explicit`, this will attempt to open `some_file.txt` and overwrite its contents.  Maybe this is what you want, but it's a pretty big side-effect that's not obvious at the calling point.  However, consider what we'd have to do since the relevant `std::ofstream` constructor is `explicit`.

```
foo(std::ofstream("some_file.txt"));
```

It's far more clear, and the caller isn't surprised (or at least shouldn't be).

Whether the type being constructed is built-in, from a third-party library, or something you wrote yourself: it's irrelevant.  `explicit` is useful anytime you don't want a type to be constructed without somebody being very explicit (hence the keyword) that's their intention.

Comment: @JaMiT I hope you are understanding that you are not giving a counter example to claim what you want to claim or be clear with that you want to say. Why bold claim, could you say more?

Comment: @JaMiT - My intention was that it's irrelevant whether the type being constructed is part of the standard library or something custom.  Is that what you're objecting to, or just the (admittedly) unclear verbiage I have right now?

Comment: @StephenNewell It was the unclear wording. Without the clarification you've added, I thought your context for "custom datatypes" was the same as the question's. The question mentions "custom datatypes as constructor argument", but you apparently meant custom datatypes as the thing being constructed. The question contrasts custom datatypes with basic types, but you apparently intended to contrast custom datatypes with library types (and with built-in types? even though built-in types -- such as `int` -- don't have constructors to mark `explicit`).

Answer (score 0):

The value that `explicit` brings when custom data types are used as constructor argument is the same as the value when basic types are used as the argument.

That really should be the end of the answer, as trying to draw a distinction between these cases is inventing a complication that does not exist. However, the OP does not accept this and has declined to clarify why this is even a question. So to give this answer content, I will show why the question fails to demonstrate a distinction. Then I will return to the nominal question and demonstrate one way in which `explicit` has value, regardless of the type of the constructor's argument.

## Implicit conversion sequences

The question shows a case where constructing a `pointA` object from an `int` fails, but this failure has nothing to do with whether the conversion is explicit or implicit. It cannot, since both `pointA` and `X` have implicit constructors. There is no way for the `explicit` specifier to come into play. The second code block in the question has no value in the context of the question. Rather than jumping to the conclusion that `explicit` has no value, the OP should have questioned why the conversion failed. The OP asked the wrong question, but we are stuck with it.

What the code in the question demonstrates is that an [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) can use at most **one** user-defined conversion. Converting an `int` to an `X` is one user-defined conversion. Converting an `X` to a `pointA` is a second user-defined conversion. You cannot use both in a single implicit conversion. Hence, the failure of the question's `pointA pa = 10;`.

### A more appropriate code example

To get a situation comparable to the first code block in the question, one should initialize with values of type `X` instead of those of type `int`. Since the first code block uses literals, let's start by looking at that case. (This is a little more complicated than the built-in case, since built-in types have built-in literals, whereas custom types do not. We'll need a user-defined literal.)

```cpp
// X, pointA, and pointB defined as in the question.

// User-defined literal X
X operator ""_X (unsigned long long i) { return static_cast<int>(i); }

// Now use an X literal in the sample code instead of an int literal.
int main()
{
    pointA pa = 10_X;   // OK
    //pointB pb = 10_X; // error: conversion from 'X' to non-scalar type 'pointB' requested
}
```

Here we use only one user-defined conversion, so an implicit conversion is possible as long as the user-defined conversion is not `explicit`. The constructor of `pointB` taking an `X` parameter is marked `explicit`, so that line fails to compile. In contrast, the `pointA` line succeeds, **just like the case where the literal was a basic type**. There is no distinction here, despite the OP's attempt to invent one.

If you don't like user-defined literals (or even if you do), you can get equivalent results by explicitly calling the user-defined conversion to `X`, as in

```cpp
    pointA pa = X{10};   // Succeeds
    //pointB pb = X{10}; // Fails
```

Again, the effect of marking one constructor `explicit` is seen.

## Leveraging `explicit`

Time to return the the nominal question being asked. What is the value of the `explicit` specifier? One benefit is avoiding expensive constructions. If `pointA` makes a shallow copy of the data in `X`, while `pointB` makes a deep copy, there could be good reason to avoid creating `pointB` objects unless that is explicitly requested. Again, it does not matter whether the parameter is of basic type or of user-defined type.

The question uses variable initialization as one example of this value. I find that a weak example, as changing `point p2 = 10;` to the more compact `point p2{10};` allows the initialization. Those who have adopted the more compact style would not notice a difference due to marking the constructor `explicit`. *There is little value of `explicit` here. The OP chose a poor example to demonstrate the value of `explicit`.*

One of the better ways to demonstrate the value of `explicit` utilizes function parameters and function overloading. Consider a function that has been overloaded to accept either a `pointA` or a `pointB` parameter.

```cpp
void fun(const pointA &) { std::cout << "fun(pointA)\n"; }
void fun(const pointB &) { std::cout << "fun(pointB)\n"; }
```

Let's go with the assumption that `pointA` is a cheap "[view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)" of an `X` object, while `pointB` is an expensive copy. If we have an `X` object to use as a parameter, we would want to convert it to a `pointA` for this function. And that is exactly what happens.

```cpp
int main() {
    X test{0};  // Assume we have this object from somewhere.

    fun(test);  // Converts `test` to `pointA` and calls that overload.
                // The overload taking a `pointB` is not called.
}
```

Both overloads are [candidate functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Candidate_functions) in overload resolution. However, the version taking a `pointB` parameter is not [viable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Viable_functions) because there is no implicit conversion from `X` to `pointB`. Hence, that version is dropped from consideration, leaving only the version taking a `pointA` parameter.

This demonstrates some of the value of marking constructors `explicit`. Expensive copies can be avoided, *without* the programmer having to think about it. In this case, not only is a potential ambiguity avoided, but also it is avoided by automatically choosing the more efficient overload.

Furthermore, this example would remain equally valid if each occurrence of `X` was replaced by `int`. *The distinction between "basic types" and "custom datatypes" is a figment of the OP's imagination. Don't buy into it.*